# "Be" used before of after

Tags: difference

Is there any difference in meaning between the following two sentences?

> If you saw a tiger what would be your reaction?
>   If you saw a tiger what would your reaction be?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in meaning.
The purists insist fthat the correct order is:

> *If you saw a tiger, what would your reaction be?*
>   What+ helping verb+ subject+ be.

Even your first sentence is acceptable in modern English.

You can say *If you saw a tiger, what would be your reaction?*

It is just a matter of style.There is no change in meaning.

The rule is:
If it is a direct question, the order is:

> What would be your reaction?

If it is an indirect question the order is:

> What would your reaction be?

It should be like a statement. The main verb should come in the end.

*What is your doubt?* (direct question)

*May I know what your doubt is?* (indirect question)